How does lift depend on velocity in 3D?
Many resources provide the following type of cross-section view when explaining aerodynamic forces:

The textbook says that $V_a$ is the speed of the aircraft through the surrounding air mass.
Does this speed include the velocity component perpendicular to the surface of this cross-section view? (i.e. velocity component coming out of the paper)
For example, suppose that there is no wind and the velocity of the aircraft is given by
$$\begin{bmatrix}u \\v \\w\end{bmatrix}$$
in body coordinates (front-right-down). If I want to calculate the lift of the main wing, what is $V_a$?

$\sqrt(u^2 + v^2 + w^2)$

or

$\sqrt(u^2 + w^2)$

Reading through the textbook seems to indicate 1. but this open source simulator
projects the velocity vector onto the lift-drag plane (XZ plane) which indicates 2.
Figure was taken from "Small Unmanned Aircraft: Theory and Practice, by Randy Beard and Tim McLain"

This can become a very long debate, since we are between two worlds here : real physics and simulation computations. To get out, you should define first what kind of optimization you want for device/computer performance reasons. That's why the 2) is the way to go for simulators, many other "minor" forces/vectors are ignored aswell. If you want to be as realistic as imaginable, you would compute everything, even swirling gusts and air masses/temperature, but good luck finding the machine that would cope with, especially if you intent to have beautiful sceneries and stunning weather effects...

The code you are using needs the velocity as given in your equation 2. because this is how lift and drag are defined/calculated in that code. The velocity component "coming out of the paper" is not needed because there's the implicit assumption that it is negligible in respect to the other two components. This assumption normally true because any airplane is laterally stable i.e. it always tends to align with the freestream given by $u$ and $w$. Only if the airplane is flying in a sideslip then also $v$ becomes important and other aerodynamic coefficients have to be taken into account as well.

Also, the curvature in that direction is typically 0 or near zero, so any crossflow will generate minimal forces.
